Centre of centralisers in connected reductive groups
Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over an algebraically closed field. Let $T$ be a maximal torus and $x\in T$. Let $G_x$ denote the centraliser of $x$ in $G$.
Question: What is an explicit description of the centre $Z(G_x)$ and $\pi_0(Z(G_x))$?
I assume this is well-known, so references would be appreciated.
Some comments: one knows that $G_x$ is a possibly disconnected reductive algebraic subgroup of $G$. More precisely, it is generated by $T$, $U_\alpha$, where $\alpha(x)=1$, and those Weyl group representatives $n_w$ which commute with $x$. The identity component $G^\circ_x$ is generated by $T$ and $U_\alpha$'s and the group of connected components $\pi_0(G_x)$ is isomorphic to $W(x)/W^\circ(x)$, where $W(x)$ is the stabiliser of $x$ in $W$ and $W^\circ(x)$ is the Weyl group of $G^{\circ}_x$.
We have an explicit description
$$Z(G_x^\circ)=\bigcap_{\alpha \in \Phi_x} \mathrm{ker}(\alpha),$$
where $\Phi_x$ is the set of roots which are equal to $1$ on $\alpha$. Moreover, $\pi_0(Z(G_x^\circ))$ is isomorphic to the prime to $p$ part of the torsion of $X/\langle \Phi_x\rangle$.

$Z(G_x)$ and $\pi_0(Z(G_x))$ are extensions of $\operatorname{ker}(W(x)/W^\circ(x) \to \operatorname{Out}(G_x^\circ))$ by $Z(G_x^\circ)^{W(x)}$ and $\pi_0(Z(G_x^\circ)^{W(x)})$, respectively, but presumably you're looking for something more explicit than that.

Thanks Loren. What is a reference for what you are stating? Perhaps you can sketch out the argument?

Sure, with a correction. Since $G_x$ is an extension of $W(x)/W^\circ(x)$ by $G_x^\circ$, we have that $Z(G_x) \cap G_x^\circ$ is $Z(G_x^\circ)^{W(x)}$. So we need to understand the image of $Z(G_x)$ in $\pi_0(G_x) = W(x)/W^\circ(x)$. Certainly this image maps trivially to $\operatorname{Out}(G_x^\circ)$. Conversely, if an element of $G_x$ maps trivially to $\operatorname{Out}(G_x^\circ)$, then it acts on $G_x^\circ$ by an inner automorphism, so can be adjusted by an element of $G_x^\circ$ to act trivially on $G_x^\circ$. …

… The correction is that, actually, there's one more condition: we have a commutator $K \times W(x)/W^\circ(x) \to G_x^\circ$, where $K \mathrel{:=} \ker(W(x)/W^\circ(x) \to \operatorname{Out}(G_x^\circ))$, which is actually in $\operatorname{Hom}(K, \operatorname{Fun}(W(x)/W^\circ(x), G_x^\circ))$, and we need our element of $K$ to lie in the kernel of this homomorphism.
